# How to determine if an object contains either master or transactional data

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

I would like to know how to determine if an object in SAP has either transactional or master data. I do not know where to locate this information if it even states it anywhere within the datasets. Also, if it has to be determined based on certain criteria then please let me know so I will not be expecting to see it as an additional field or something. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such criterion, it's up to context, if we speak about custom tables. It's up to the company that uses SAP what is transactional in their business, and what is master.

If we speak about standard tables, then you can use [Data Class](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi71/helpdata/en/cf/21eac5446011d189700000e8322d00/frameset.htm) (reachable by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on target table):

[image]

However, this attribute also cannot be treated as a 100% reliable way.